# Prove that two separated sets must be relatively open in their union

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm working in the plane here. My idea was that if A is open, then let O = A and then O intersect (A union B) = A, since A and B are separated, so A is relatively open in A union B. If A is not open, then there are some points in A that have neighborhoods not contained in A. I'll make an aggregate set called P of those points. Then, since A and B are separated, each of these points has a neighborhood containing no points in A. If I let O = (A union N_p) for all p in P, then O intersect (A union B) = A. Furthermore, O is open since each point in A\P is in O and has a neighborhood in A, and, thus, has a neighborhood in O, and each point in P has a neighborhood in O. Thus, A is still relatively open in A union B.

My professor didn't think this was a valid solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can prove that if the union of two separated sets is open, then they are in fact both open. This result descends to the subspace topology and allows you to conclude they are relatively open.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two separated sets in a space $X$ (no need to use anything specific to the plane). This means that $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset = A \cap \overline{B}$. In particular this means that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. So to see that $A$ is relatively open in $C = A \cup B$, it is enough to see that its complement (in $C$!), which is $B$, is relatively closed in $C$, and the same holds (mutatis mutandis) for $B$.

So we need to see that $A$ and $B$ are relatively closed in $C$.

Now, in general, $\overline{A}^{(C)} = \overline{A} \cap C$, for every subset $C$ of $X$ and every $A \subset C$, and where the first term is the closure of $A$ in the relative (subspace) topology of $C$. Apply this to $C = A \cup B$:

$$\overline{A}^{(A \cup B)} = \overline{A} \cap (A \cup B) = (\overline{A} \cap A) \cup (\overline{A} \cap B) = A,$$ because $A \subset \overline{A}$ and $A$ and $B$ are separated.    Hence, $A$ is closed in $C$ (and so $B = C \setminus A$ is open in $C$), and the same holds for $B$ again, interchanging the roles.

Comment: In the second last line we get that  A¯¯¯¯(A∪B) = A . since A¯¯¯¯ is closed this implies its complement is open in C, i.e; A is open. May be I am wrong. Please help me.

Comment: We get $\overline{A}^{(A\cup B)}  =A$ so $A$ is closed in $C = A \cup B$. So $B$ is open in $C$ (as its relative complement). You still have to prove $B$ is closed in $C$ (so that $A$ is open in $C$), but like I said, this goes the same way.

Comment: Thanks,now I got it.